# SharePoint 2013 suddenly start raising the following error:- HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, central-administration

The SharePoint server 2013 was working well inside windows sever 2008 r2, but suddenly I start getting the following error when trying to access the sharepoint administration UI:-

```
Service Unavailable

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

And when I run the SharePoint 2013 product configuration wizard I will get the following exception:-

> 9/09/2013 13:29:09  1  INF                Not running in high
>   contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
>   09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  ERR                Task upgradebootstrap has
>   failed with an unknown exception  09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  ERR
>   Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Exception
>   of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown. 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPManager.BootStrap(Guid sessionId,
>   SPUpgradeOperationFlags flags)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeBootstrapTask.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
>   09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF                Entering function
>   Common.BuildExceptionMessage 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF
>   Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString 09/09/2013
>   13:29:18  11  INF                    Resource id to be retrieved is
>   ExceptionInfo for language English (United States) 09/09/2013 13:29:18
>   11  INF                    Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An
>   exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information:
>   {1} 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF                  Leaving function
>   StringResourceManager.GetResourceString 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF
>   Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11 
>   INF                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
>   09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF                  Entering function
>   Common.BuildExceptionMessage 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF
>   Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString 09/09/2013
>   13:29:18  11  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is
>   ExceptionInfo for language English (United States) 09/09/2013 13:29:18
>   11  INF                      Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An
>   exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information:
>   {1} 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF                    Leaving function
>   StringResourceManager.GetResourceString 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11  INF
>   Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage 09/09/2013 13:29:18  11 
>   INF                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation

Comment: Did u tried starting the associated Application pool account from IIS manager

Comment: i restart the whole server, but nothing was changed..

Comment: yes all the site are start inside the IIS manager.

Comment: No..i am saying about Application pool..check that as well...

Comment: yes you are right under the application pool, the central admin was stopped. but why did it stop suddenly ?

Comment: Its a mystery for me as well...may when my knowledge grows up I could provide a proper answer.

Comment: Pls mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check for the Application pool and the website in IIS manager of your Sharepoint site are running. Sometimes it gets stopped. So you need to make sure that they both are in started mode.

Comment: yes it was stopped !!!!